# Is the Authorization Code Grant still necessary when using TLS?

Tags: ssl, oauth, tls1.2

The primary purpose of an authorization code in the oAuth flow is to prevent replay attacks, TLS also prevents replay attacks.

If you simply made a password grant request to an oAuth enabled server using TLS would that not be sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

> The primary purpose of an authorization code in the oAuth flow is to
> prevent replay attacks

I think the primary purpose of Authorization Code flow is different then prevent replay attacks. OAuth does not guarantee this and regardless of the grant, OAuth 2.0 [suggests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.3) us use always TLS for all grants to transmit Access token:

> Access token credentials MUST only be transmitted using TLS    as
> described in Section 1.6 with server authentication as defined by
> [RFC2818].

There are also other grants in OAuth 2.0 like;

- Authorization Code
- PKCE
- Implicit (**Legacy**)
- Client Credentials
- Password (**Legacy**)
- Device Code
- Refresh Token

and each has its own purpose. Password flow is legacy and you should have a strong reason to keep using it because of the following reasons:

- Your user exposing their credentials to 3rd party for no reason. It was the reason OAuth exist, not sharing credentials to 3rd party (like e.g: Service Foo) to get access to their service (like Google, Facebook)
- User does not have any control what your **Service Foo** can do with these credentials.

It was required before like Implicit flow, but both Password and Implicit flows are replaced now with Device and PKCE based on their usage. For instance; if the main reason one application uses Password Grant is their clients can not support redirection, they can also use now Device Code Grant.